# Remove string between () including () in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, charindex

I have a `name` column which in some of the the cells contains a bracketed string.

Examples:

```
Smith (Divorced)
Jones
Janes
Renold (Deaceased)...
```

and so on. I need to remove the bracketed section completly.

```
Smith
Jones
Janes
Renold
```

Tried various `CHARINDEX`'s and `REPLACE` but either get an invalid lenght error or it only removes part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you basically need, just modify it to suit your query:

```
declare @tmp table (name varchar(100))
insert @tmp values ('smith (divorced)' ) , ('jones'), ('renold (deceased)...')

select name
    , case 
        when charindex('(', name, 1) > 0 
            then rtrim(left(name, charindex('(', name, 1) - 1)) 
        else name 
      end as [name]
from @tmp
```

If you need to replace the data that you have, just issue an `UPDATE`, like below:

```
UPDATE Persons_Table
SET Name = case 
            when charindex('(', Name, 1) > 0 
                then rtrim(left(Name, charindex('(', Name, 1) - 1)) 
            else Name 
          end
WHERE charindex('(', Name, 1) > 0 -- could prove useful since you might not want to go
                                  -- over all of the data
```